# Display A4 pdf in div responsive with HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

**EDIT: I solved it: it was in the settings of the pdf that I needed to change the mode to 'Page Fit'**

I try to display a pdf in a div that is exactly a half of my screen.

I don't want to have to scroll to see the single A4 pdf page.

When I resize the screen I also wan't the pdf to get bigger/smaller.

The problem is that the embeded pdf is not resizing itself and it is scrollable.

**CSS**:

```
split {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}

embed#pdf {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="split left">
    <embed id="pdf" src="my_pdf.pdf" type='application/pdf'>
</div>
```

I have tried to use the  tag, but I get the same result.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you missed postion:absolute ?

Comment: use object tag instead of embed?

Comment: No, it doesen't work! I still get the scrollbar and when I resize my window, it is still the same size @TemaniAfif

Comment: When I use object tag I have the exact same result! @NegiRox

Comment: have youfix some height and width for object tag?

Comment: Yes I have replaced the embed tag in CSS with the object tag @NegiRox

Comment: you can not set the css of pdf... but you can only manage the wrapper

Comment: Ok I got it, it was in the pdf settings I needed to select Page Fit! Sorry for the disturbing!!! Thank you for the help!@NegiRox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it: it was in the settings of the pdf that I needed to change the mode to 'Page Fit'